# Button text is cut and not centered

Tags: swift, button, properties

I create a button using a storyboard, which is assigned the cornerRadius, borderWidth, textAlignment, and clipsToBounds properties. And by code I assigned the following text to fit the width of the button. But when executing it isn't vertical center and also it is visualized cut.

```
añadirOtrosCursos.titleLabel?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
añadirOtrosCursos.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 1              
añadirOtrosCursos.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
añadirOtrosCursos.contentVerticalAlignment = .center
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking on the UIButton in Main.storyboard, going to the attributes inspector, scrolling down to the "control" category, and making sure that the vertical alignment is set to center. [This is what you should see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkVTn.png).

Comment: Yes, I set center in both

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple thing just open your storyboard, select your button and change the button property as below screenshot.

[image: Please do as follows]